# How to run other program with the web server running in VPS with SSH connection?

Tags: python, vps, web.py

I log on my VPS with SSH method and set up a test web page with web.py

After I run the server with below command, the VPS come into the server state and I can't do other things to the VPS, e.g. open a browser to check if the server works...

Anyone know how can I do other thing with the server running? In the local computer, it seems no problem obviously.

My terminal operation screen shot
[image]

my main.py code is as follows:

```
# filename: main.py
import web

urls = (
    '/wx', 'Handle',
)

class Handle(object):
    def GET(self):
        return "hello, this is a test"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = web.application(urls, globals())
    app.run()
```

Comment: Did you try to run your script in background as `python main.py 8080 &` ?

Comment: @Andersson Thanks, I didn't know this "&" method before.

Comment: By the way, to end up this background task, we could use "jobs" to show the task and use "kill" to end it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Script is working properly. The `app.run()` call puts the program in an infinite loop waiting for clients to connect with it.

As @Andersson suggests, you could execute the script, putting it in the background. Or, open another SSH session and use one window for your script & another for whatever else you want to do on your server.

For production systems, you should run web.py under nginx or apache.

See http://webpy.org/cookbook/, scroll down to "Deployments", for guidance on running under Apache and Nginx.

Comment: Thanks, according to you guys' suggestion, I successfully put it into the background and at the same time I could run other program freely.

Comment: @Peter Do u have a link to any site that has explained how to host web.py in Apache for windows?